# When is International Tabletop Day?

Tags: events

I have heard of "International Tabletop Day" being a celebration of board games and roleplaying games, and that some stores have events for it. When is that?

Also, do previous dates provide any clues as to when we can expect future dates to be so that stores etc. can plan accordingly?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the schedule of an event, not about board or card games.

Comment: [Meta discussion](http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/1466/3389) about our policy on gaming related events.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[International Tabletop Day](https://www.tabletopday.com) has been hosted by [Geek & Sundry](http://geekandsundry.com) every year since 2013,* but the schedule has been somewhat inconsistent as to when it is. I had a hard time finding the dates, especially for the early ones, but here they are:

- [March 30, 2013](http://herocomplex.latimes.com/games/international-tabletop-day-wil-wheaton-wants-you-to-play-board-games/)
- [April 5, 2014](https://twitter.com/GeekandSundry/statuses/425090935064891392)
- [April 11, 2015](http://nerdist.com/geek-sundry-announces-international-tabletop-day-for-2015/)
- [April 30, 2016](https://geekandsundry.com/geek-sundry-announces-international-tabletop-day-2016/)
- [April 29, 2017](https://www.tabletopday.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-international-tabletop-day-2017/)
- [April 28, 2018](https://www.tabletopday.com/join-geek-sundry-for-international-tabletop-day-on-april-28-2018/)

If the pattern for the last couple of years holds, then one would expect that in the future it will be held on the last Saturday in April.

<sup>* The logo for International TableTop Day says that it's "since 2012", but I cannot find any evidence that it was actually held in that year. @PatLudwig in the comments provides supporting evidence that 2013 was the first.</sup>

Comment: 2013 was the first - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x3m0PIWqkfQ